# How to break out of a while loop if a blank line or null is entered?

Tags: kotlin

I would like to ask the user for input of "Any" type (strings, ints, double, etc.) and add them to a mutablelist. However I can't seem to find a way to break out the while loop when a blank line or null value is entered. Here's and example of what I'm trying. Thank you.

```
val someInfo = mutableListOf<Any>()

while (true){
    someInfo.add(readLine()!!)
    //how to break out of this loop when a user enters a blank line or null value?

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest way is probably just

```
while(true) {
    val input = readLine()
    if (input.isNullOrEmpty()) break // or isNullOrBlank (includes empty whitespace)
    // do stuff
}
```

if you want to do a Kotlin and skip the loops, you could

```
generateSequence { readLine() }
    .takeWhile { !it.isNullOrEmpty() }
    .forEach { // do a thing }
```

Comment: Replace `forEach` with `toList()` for this specific case and you don't even have to fool with the MutableList. Also, `generateSequence` already ends on the first null value so you could change the second line to `takeWhile { it.isNotEmpty() }`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the result value of `readLine()` before deciding what to do:

```kotlin
while(true) {
    when(val result = readLine().orEmpty()) {
        // result is an empty string, break out the loop
        "" -> break
        else -> someInfo.add(result)
    }
}
```

Should do the trick.

The `String?.orEmpty()` kotlin extension function converts any `null` value into an empty `String` so no need to worry to check for `null`. Still, here you may want to watch out for any exception

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I've tried your suggestion but now i'm getting an error on the result.isNotEmpty()    statement. Incompatible types: Boolean and String. Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry for the belated answer. Yes This was a mistake. it should be `"" -> ` instead of `result.isNotEmpty()` because we're comparing the `String` result